# Data handling in fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

Im currently developing an Android application. As I want to support tablets as well as phones I decided to use fragments. But now appears one question which is more an architecture question than a concrete error.

Which component is responsible for loading and saving data: the surrounding activity or the fragment itself? All examples in android developer resources use data loading in fragment.

My application (simplified):

- ItemActivity (shows ItemListFragment)
- EditItemActivity (shows EditItemFragment)
- CreateItemActivity (shows EditItemFragment)
- ItemListFragment (shows a list of items from local SqliteDb)
- EditItemFragment (allows to edit an item, loads and saves it from
  SqliteDb)

But I think I'm stuck now. So my question is more a general one regarding best practises.

1. I want to set arguments in fragment, but this only works when adding fragments dynamically to the activity. So how to pass arguments from activity to fragment when using fix fragments?
2. I can access my database, when activity is created in lifecycle. But I have to make decision on whether data should be loaded before in lifecycle. onCreate and onCreateView and savedInstanceState decide whether I should restore from bundle or load from database later. So should I store in onCreate whether to load from database or not or is there a better approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FOA I advise you to use only fragments instead of fragments for tabs and activities for smartphones. The reason why Im saying this:

> My application (simplified):
>
> ItemActivity (shows ItemListFragment) 
>   EditItemActivity (shows EditItemFragment) 
>   CreateItemActivity (shows EditItemFragment)
>   ItemListFragment (shows a list of items from local SqliteDb)
>   EditItemFragment (allows to edit an item, loads and saves it from SqliteDb)

I guess first three has to be fragments as well. Secondly you could use any data containers you want - Bundle with args, SharedPreferences even some public fields in parent activity.
So how to pass arguments from activity to fragment when using fix fragments?
You could instantiate your fragment via static method like:

```
private int photoRes;
public static ViewPagerDetailFragment newInstance(int photoRes) {
    final ViewPagerDetailFragment f = new ViewPagerDetailFragment();
    f.photoRes = photoRes;
    return f;
}
```

or use Bundle

```
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putInt(KEY,value);
Fragment fragment = new Fragment();
fragment.setArguments(args);
```

as for 2 - I guess its better to show UI to user first and then do data loads, in other way (load data in onCreate etc) it could look like ANR. If data amount is low then it could be loaded in onCreate or wherever you want. If amount is big its better to use loaders to load data from DB

Comment: Both approaches are clear to me and are very similar. I create the fragment in code and pass arguments and let the fragment handle the data.

But there's the activity lifecycle. Maybe I misunderstood something. My fragment has to decide whether to load data from database or show the original data (e.g. after rotation change).

Answer (score 0):

Fragments should be considered kind of autonomous entities, therefore in most cases all data load/save should be handled or triggered by fragments.

For passing arguments to fragment - either rework your code and pass args in code, or expose public method from fragments.

As for accessing DB - access it whenever you want to use that data.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use Otto library and have singleton models being producers of data and `Fragments` subscribers.

Answer (score 0):

You'll definitely want to load the data in the fragment. I'm guessing that some of your activities will only be for phone layouts, and that you'll combine some of the fragments into one activity if you're on a larger device. And maybe later you'll decide to reuse the fragments in other activities (or even nested within other fragments). You should therefore aim to make each fragment as independent as possible. Try not to couple them to your activities.

This includes loading your data from a database. Are there specific reasons that your database must be loaded in the activity and not in the Fragment? Perhaps you need a context to load your database: you can just use `Fragment#getActivity()` to get one. There's also `Fragment#onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)` if you need to ensure that an Activity has been created and views have been setup. If I were you, I'd load your data in the `onActivityCreated` method of the Fragment. And I'd be sure to use a [`CursorLoader`](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html) so it doesn't slow down the UI and I don't have to worry about managing it.

If you still need to talk to your fixed Fragment from the Activity (you probably will), you can grab your fragment from the Activity's fragment manager, like so:

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
(MyFragment) myFragment = (MyFragment)fm.findFragmentByTag(tagName);
```

Just be sure to set a tag name for your fragment in your XML. (You can also assign and find your Fragment by an id; use `FragmentManager#findFragmentById()` instead.)

Really though, if you need to set arguments before your Fragment is created, it's better to do it dynamically.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know the lifecycle of the surrounding activity is responsible for loading and saving the data. In Activity.onResume() you can trigger the initialisation of the fragment fields.